# Check if files exist using Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a Powershell script which I've cobbled together. It uses an external file as a lookup then checks the LastWriteTime of those files.

This was created as a checking procedure. To ensure a set of files had been updated each day.

However, I've noticed that if the files don't exist at run time, they don't show in the list at all. So there's potential for these to be missed.

As well as checking the LastWriteDate, is there a way this can be altered to highlight in some way if any of the files don't exist?

Either a new column saying Exists Y/N?

Or even a total row count VS expected row count?

This is what I've got so far...

```
#Filelist - This is a simple txt file with various filepaths entered
$filelist = Get-Content "H:\PowerShell\Files_Location_List.txt"


$results = foreach ($file in $filelist) {
                                            Get-Item $file | select -Property fullname, LastWriteTime #| Measure-Object
                                        }
$results | Export-Csv 'H:\PowerShell\File_Modified_Dates.csv' -NoTypeInformation #| Measure-Object
```

The contents of Files_Location_List.txt is very simple...

\server\folder\file1.csv

\server\folder\file2.csv

\server\folder\file3.csv

etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` on `Get-Item` to either get a FileInfo object if the file exists or $null if not:

```
# Filelist - This is a simple txt file with various filepaths entered
$result = Get-Content "H:\PowerShell\Files_Location_List.txt" | ForEach-Object {
    # try and get the FileInfo object for this path. Discard errors
    $file = Get-Item -Path $_ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($file) { 
        $file | Select-Object -Property FullName, LastWriteTime, @{Name = 'Exists'; Expression = {$true}}
    }
    else {
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            FullName = $_
            LastWriteTime = $null
            Exists = $false
        }
    }
}
$result | Export-Csv 'H:\PowerShell\File_Modified_Dates.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I had to remove one of the curly brackets on 2nd to last line to get that working. When it ran, it didn't quite give me what I was hoping for. I'd like it to highlight if any items don't exist.

Comment: @glass_kites The extra curly bracket was a typo. Please see the edit. Now it outputs objects with an extra property 'Exists', also on files that were not found.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

you can try using [Test-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path?view=powershell-7.1)

```
if(Test-Path -Path <file_path>) {
# do stuff
}
```